# How to tile svg print output dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, dynamic, tile

I have  large svg drawings, with unknown sizes at the beginning. I want to print them on multiple pages; but the number of pages are not known initially. So I have to decide on the number of pages within Javascript after I idetify the drawing size and add svg elements accordingly.

There is a nice example at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/roYXVJ which is a "static" tiling, i.e., the size and number of pages are fixed beforehand. A simplified version of the code (without the arrows and index letters) looks like the following:

```
<figure class="svg-container">
  <!-- The actual graphic is a 3:2 image
       which will be wrapped in a scrolling
       container on screen. -->
  <svg class="screen" width="18in" height="12in"
       viewBox="0 0 1800 1200">
    <g id="graphic"><!-- 
      Actual graphic goes here.  I'm using a script to generate it. 
--></g>
  </svg>
  <!-- For printing in landscape mode,
       the graphic is divided into four
       overlapping quadrants which will
       each fit on a letter/A4 page
       without scaling.  The 1000*700 viewBox
       is equivalent to 10in*7in of the
       onscreen dimensions. -->
  <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="0 0 1000 700">
    <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="800 0 1000 700">
    <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="0 500 1000 700">
    <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="800 500 1000 700">
    <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
  </svg>

  <!-- For printing in portrait mode,
       the graphic is scaled down slightly
       to fit on two pages.  Again,
       the content of each page will 
       overlap slightly. -->
  <svg class="print portrait" viewBox="0 0 1000 1200">
    <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="print portrait" viewBox="800 0 1000 1200">
    <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
  </svg>
</figure>

<script>

var doc = document;
var g = doc.getElementById("graphic");
var svgNS = g.namespaceURI;
var r, t;

for (var i=0; i<18; i++){
  for (var j=0; j<12; j++) {
    r = doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    r.setAttribute("width", "80");
    r.setAttribute("height", "80");
    r.setAttribute("x", (i*100 + 10));
    r.setAttribute("y", (j*100 + 10));
    r.style.setProperty("fill-opacity", ((i*j + 1)%20)/20, null);
    g.insertBefore(r, null);
    t = doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "text");
    t.setAttribute("x", (i*100 + 50));
    t.setAttribute("y", (j*100 + 50));
    t.setAttribute("class", "diagram")
    t.textContent = [i,j];
    g.insertBefore(t, null);
  }  
}

</script>
```

So, I am trying to replace

```
<svg class="print landscape"...  />
```

static definitions with such dynamic definitions within the script:
EDIT: I correct some definitions and added some missing ones. Updated dynamic definitions are:

```
var printLandscape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
printLandscape.setAttribute("viewBox", " 800 500 1000 700");
printLandscape.setAttribute("orientation", "landscape");
printLandscape.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#graphic");
printLandscape.setAttribute("class", "print landscape")
g.insertBefore(printLandscape, null);
```

But that (STILL) does not work. What would be the correct way to get  similar output dynamically?

After some research I understand xlink:href is not an attribute of the svg since it is used by the "use" function(?). So, another use element should be defined to point to xlink:href. Also, printLanscape should be part of the container, "figure". Final definitions are as follows:

```
var doc = document;
var g = doc.getElementById("graphic");
var f = doc.getElementById("mafigure");
var svgNS = g.namespaceURI;

var printLandscape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
var useElem = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'use');

printLandscape.setAttributeNS(svgNS,"class", "print landscape")
printLandscape.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "viewBox", " 800 500 1000 700");
useElem.setAttributeNS(svgNS, 'xlink:href', '#graphic');
printLandscape.appendChild(useElem);
f.insertBefore(printLandscape, null);
```

Now, with these definitions I have the fourth page appeared in the tiling, but it is empty. There must be some more error or missing things in linking output data to the tile page.

EDIT: Here is full test case. HTML document with embedded svg and javascript. It provides 4- page static tiling. I took out the fourth static page definition and tried to implement a dynamic tile definitin within the Javascript.

So now, it prints three pages correctly. There is fourth page, but blank, with the content missing.

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <style>
 symbol, use, svg {
   overflow: visible;
 }
 rect {
   stroke: navy;
 }

 /* Screen styles */
 figure.svg-container {
   display: block;
   overflow: scroll;
   max-width: 90vw;
   max-height: 90vh;
   border:gray solid thin;
 }

 svg.print {
   display: none;
 }
 @media print{
   figure.svg-container {
     display: inline;
     overflow: auto;
     border: none;
   }
   svg.screen {
     display: none;
   }
   svg.print {
     overflow: hidden;
     border: thin lightgray solid;
     padding: 0.5em;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     page-break-inside: avoid;
     break-inside: avoid;
   }
 }
 @media print and (orientation: landscape){
   svg.print.landscape {
     display: block;
     height: 7in;
     width: 10in;
   }
 }
 @media print and (orientation: portrait){
   svg.print.portrait {
     display: block;
     height: 9in;
     width: 7.5in;
   }
 }

 </style>

 <figure class="svg-container" id="mafigure">
   <!-- The actual graphic is a 3:2 image
        which will be wrapped in a scrolling
        container on screen. -->
   <svg class="screen" width="18in" height="12in"
        viewBox="0 0 1800 1200">
     <g id="graphic"><!-- 
       Actual graphic goes here.  I'm using a script to generate it. 
 --></g>
   </svg>
   <!-- For printing in landscape mode,
        the graphic is divided into four
        overlapping quadrants which will
        each fit on a letter/A4 page
        without scaling.  The 1000*700 viewBox
        is equivalent to 10in*7in of the
        onscreen dimensions. -->
   <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="0 0 1000 700">
     <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
   </svg>
   <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="800 0 1000 700">
     <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
   </svg>
   <svg class="print landscape" viewBox="0 500 1000 700">
     <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
   </svg>

   <!-- For printing in portrait mode,
        the graphic is scaled down slightly
        to fit on two pages.  Again,
        the content of each page will 
        overlap slightly. -->
   <svg class="print portrait" viewBox="0 0 1000 1200">
     <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
   </svg>
   <svg class="print portrait" viewBox="800 0 1000 1200">
     <use xlink:href="#graphic" />
   </svg>
 </figure>

 <script>

 var r, t;

 var doc = document;
 var g = doc.getElementById("graphic");
 var f = doc.getElementsByClassName("svg-container");
 var svgNS = g.namespaceURI;

 var printLandscape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
 var useElem = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'use');

 printLandscape.setAttributeNS(svgNS,"class", "print landscape")
 printLandscape.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "viewBox", " 800 500 1000 700");
 useElem.setAttributeNS(svgNS, 'xlink:href', '#graphic');
 printLandscape.appendChild(useElem);
 f[0].appendChild(printLandscape);

 for (var i=0; i<18; i++){
   for (var j=0; j<12; j++) {
     r = doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
     r.setAttribute("width", "80");
     r.setAttribute("height", "80");
     r.setAttribute("x", (i*100 + 10));
     r.setAttribute("y", (j*100 + 10));
     r.style.setProperty("fill-opacity", ((i*j + 1)%20)/20, null);
     g.insertBefore(r, null);
   }  
 }

 </script>

 <body>

 </body>

 </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlink:href` is in the xlink namespace, not the svg namespace. Actually, the use of the namespace is deprecated, and practically all browsers understand the `href` attribute without a namespace. Simply write

```
useElem.setAttribute('href', '#graphic');
```

Comment: I do not understand why the review board keeps bugging the question owner. As you can see, people can read, understand and answer the question quietly, peacefuly , and more importantly. usefully.